# How to solve Structured Data and Syntax problems in Wordpress (Google Search Console notified me) - Photos in links of Imgur

Tags: wordpress

Okay, since I tried to add structured data with Schema, several errors have occurred to me, and now that I have removed the wordpress plugin, they are still there, and there are even more problems, I have been trying to fix them for a long time and I just can't.

I will leave the following problems on the list:

***Mistakes:***
**In structured data**, the type of value is not correct.

**In products**, the score scale could not be determined and the value of the "reviewCount" property must be positive.

***Warnings:***
**In products**, the *"priceValidUntil"* field is missing, the *"review"* field is missing, the *"url"* field is missing, the *"sku"* field is missing, no international identifier has been provided, such as a GTIN, MPN or ISBN, missing the *"description"* field

I do not know if the problem is solved by changing the code in my wordpress, but I do not know how it is changed, uninstall the plugin all in one schema and it is not cured.

[Image of Error with links in sites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypp48.png)

[Image of Errors With Structured Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihPBO.png)

[Image of Errors Ands Warnings eith products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXo9S.png)

[Image of my Performance in Google Search Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0QTQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. This is typical for schema markup and structured data that gets added in by a plugin. I stopped using the plugin and now add my own structured data. If you add your own, you have full control and can make these easy fixes.

Sounds like you know what code needs to be changed/added but cannot access it because the plugin added it somewhere in your HTML.

In this case I'd suggest leaving the existing code as is. Create your new structured data (the correct codes) and also add that in. There is no issue with having multiple sets so Google will ignore the data with errors.

There is a simple plugin that will add your scheme to the head of your posts or pages. Generating your structured data is also easy. Here is a guide for how to do all of this. https://master-influencer.com/how-to-add-structured-data-schema-markup-improve-your-seo-performance-rich-results-easy-way-wordpress-website/

Hope this helps.

Best,
Shaun